# Why does my node-statsd client script not exit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, statsd

A simple call to log a metric to a [StatsD](https://github.com/etsy/statsd) server, using the [node-statsd](https://github.com/sivy/node-statsd) library, results in the script not exiting automatically. I have the following code:

```
var StatsD = require('node-statsd').StatsD;
var client = new StatsD();

client.increment('test.counter', 1, 1, [], function (err, bytes) {
  console.log('called back', err, bytes);
});
console.log('End of script');
```

As I understand it, this means there is a callback registered that has not fired. I don't understand how, though. I am passing in a callback function, which is being executed.

I'm worried about using this in an application with a lot of metrics being sent to the StatsD server - I can imagine a lot of callbacks hanging around forever.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually close the socket connection with `client.socket.close()` after your callback.

```
client.increment('test.counter', 1, 1, [], function (err, bytes) {
  console.log('called back', err, bytes);
  client.socket.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that did point me in the right direction. The socket seems to be opened when the client is created. If I close it as you suggest, I cannot send any more metrics with that client. The right thing to do seems to be to close the socket when the application exits - but again, that might be unnecessary.